# fcntl.lockf inside a context manager of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a piece of code (python 3.7) that is as below:

```py
import os, fcntl

with open("testfile", 'w') as tf:
    fcntl.lockf(tf.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.lock_NB)
    ... some code that does some stuff ...
    tf.write("%s got here first!!" % (os.getpid())
    fcntl.lockf(tf.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html) of `io` and `open` (the inbuilt function), the IOBase is also a context manager which ensures that the file is closed after the `with` statement's suite is finished, even if an exception occurs.

Now, let's say we have two **processes** (not threads) p1, p2 running this code.

p1 got there first and got the exclusive lock on this file, hence p2 threw an IOError. I have three questions in this scenario:

1. would p2 execute the code after the first `fcntl.lockf` or will it just exit the block of code of the `with` statement and call `__exit__` method of the file object?
2. if ans to 1 is YES, would p2 blank the file when the context manager of p2 gets executed after p1's context manager? isn't there a possibility of a race condition here? Sometimes p1 may win and flush+close its stream before p2 and sometimes p2 before p1. Whoever flushes and closes the file last, would have its contents in the file. Is my analysis correct?
3. since i'm `open`ing the file in `'w'` mode, the file would be truncated by both p1 and p2 when they create the file objects in their memory. I would like this to happen only if the process gets to the file first? I couldn't find a way 
   to first open the file exclusively in `'w'` mode and then lock it.

Thanks!